# Creating mobile version of the Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

We have website that was developed for desktops and now I've been blessed with a task of creating mobile version of it. The mobile design might be quite different from desktop version and the website is build on Wordpress. Now I'm not sure what would be best approach:

1. shall I stick to CSS changes only (as much as possible) and use media queries to target smaller screens? I'm worried about large images still being downloaded even if these are display:none. There is also quite a bit of JS happening on every page and this JS will not be used in mobile version of the site so I would have to build in additional checks possibly etc. Any other possbile problems with this approach?
2. server side code should detect if its mobile browser and should return custom html? Any other possbile problems with this approach?
3. mixture of two above?
4. any other options?

If anyone has experience with similar project and could point me to what proffered solution would be that would be great.

Comment: I think this depends on *how* different the mobile version will be. If it's only minor differences in styling and layout, you could probably use CSS media queries. If it's a completely different site, you would probably want to serve (or redirect) to a mobile version of the site. That being said, I don't have experience with WordPress, so I don't know if there are any WP-specific solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries as much as possible for layout changes.
For you JS, create yourself a small breakpoint handler that will trigger the js to run or stop.

I think a lot of people don't realize that a 2x image compressed is smaller than a 1x image compressed.  So, if you use compression for you images, you will actually get a better network performance using just large images.  How much of that image gets displayed is a potential issue that can cause negative performance, but I imagine that it's insignificant.

Are you using completely different UI for mobile than for desktop or is is just a different positioning of elements?  If you have to support two templates then you will want o think about Adaptive(responsive from the server), where the server will determine based on the UserAgent which template to send to the client.  UserAgent wont really get you much except for the type of Browser the client has.  To figure out the dimensions of the device's screen you will need to know the dimensions or use a service like WURFL.

If you can do all of your UI change in one template using media queries then it might be best to start working on this from a Mobile First approach and basically start from scratch on your mobile look of the site and then figure out how you can re-position the elements on the page to match as close as possible to the current desktop look.  Using the Responsive vs Adaptive approach will eliminate the need for UserAgent detection and you will only work with the width of the device.

Thinking of Responsive in "Mobile" vs "Desktop" is really limiting and causes a bit of confusion.  Mobile should refer to devices that change location.  Try using names like small, medium, and large to describe the layouts(breakpoints) for your Responsive Page.

Finally, there is not preferred way of doing "Responsive."  Each site will have it's own requirements that need to be met.  It is up to you to learn as much as possible and create the preferred way for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of the Responsive Theme Wordpress has. It is very customizable, and will allow you to use one site for both Mobile and Desktop.

https://wordpress.org/themes/responsive

Answer (score 0):

You could always use:

```
 <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
```

in your header. Then the whole site will resize to fit the mobile device.

All your js should still work on mobile devices. It would just be 'flash' that wouldn't.

The site isn't "responsive" with this but, depending on the site and how much interaction etc the visitor needs, sometimes this is adequate and simple?